# setting width in seaborn: bar() got multiple values for argument 'width'

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I simply want to manually adjust the width of a barplot in seaborn but I run into the error TypeError: bar() got multiple values for argument 'width'

This is what produced the error:

```
#create DataFrame
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'employee': ['Andy'],
                   'sales': [22]})

#create bar plot with width = 0.4
sns.barplot(x='employee', y='sales', data=df, width=0.4)
```

As a workaround, I tried setting patch.set_width():

```
#create DataFrame
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'employee': ['Andy'],
                   'sales': [22]})

#create bar plot with width = 0.4 
# now using patch.set_width
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))
ax.patch.set_width(0.6)
ax = sns.barplot(x='employee', y='sales', data=df)
```

However, this decenters the bar, which I don't want. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't have issues with pandas 1.5.3, matplotlib 3.6.3, seaborn 0.12.2, you might want to update

Comment: Same for me  for same versions. (except for matplotlib 3.5.2). I can reproduce the problem with `seaborn==0.11.2`

Comment: If you are on older version and using second option, just before the `ax=barplot()`, you can move the bar to the right a little by adding `ax.patch.set_x(ax.patch.get_x()+0.2)`

Comment: Seaborn 12.2 has a width parameter, 11.2 does not hav a width parameter.

Comment: See https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/3137